# Windows 10 - Option to add and manage APN's missing

Tags: windows-10, cellular

Using Win 10 IoT Enterprise 2016 LTSB 64Bit

This is been deployed onto 300+ tablet devices with built in 4G. We're using a specific M2M SIM provider and as a result I need to update the APN details on the device.

I can do this via scripts using netsh but I also expect to be able to do this via the windows UI.

I expect to able to do this in: Settings -> Network & Internet -> Cellular -> Advanced options.

Under 'Mobile Operator Settings' I should be able to see and add APNs, however the option isn't present.

[image: https://i.imgur.com/CU5acBe.png]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*The following is written, assuming APN altering from GUI is necessary and `netsh` command usage to enable it is acceptable. But complete avoidance of `netsh` is not needed.*

I had a similar problem after installation and deinstallation of software bundled with my usb 3G modem.
I couldn't edit APN in UI and at connection attempts I was receiving `"Can't connect to this network. Enter an APN and try again"`, but no option to enter APN (like on Damo's screenshot)

I solved it using

```
netsh mbn delete profile interface="Mobile Broadband Connection" name="myProfileName"
```

Instead of `"Mobile Broadband Connection"` use value of field "`name`" returned by

```
netsh mbn show interfaces
```

And instead of `"myProfileName"` use value returned by

```
netsh mbn show profiles
```

After that OS (Win 10 Enterprise 2016 LTSB 64Bit) almost immediately (or after pressing connection icon in tray? I don't remember exactly now) automatically have created a new connection profile, where APN could be altered from OS's GUI.

If instruction above doesn't help and OS (or some other software) again generates new profile with APN editing disabled, try to copy .XML file (some configurations would also need .ICO, referenced in .XML) from `%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\Microsoft\WwanSvc\Profiles` to temporary location, edit it, delete profile (as written above) and reapply edited .XML using `netsh mbn add profile`.

Try to change in that .XML values of `ProfileCreationType` and/or `AuthProtocol` fields to something else listed in the following links:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd323293(v=vs.85).aspx
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd323274(v=vs.85).aspx